# Cannot update a mark by using Store Procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, addition

I was trying to use store procedure to update a mark result in the mark table. It was fine when running the script but it changed nothing. Does anyone know what I wrote wrong in the script?

Here is some information about the tables:
Student - Contains SID and CourseID
Course - CourseID and DeptID
Department - DeptID
Modules - ModuleID and DeptID
Mark - ModuleID, SID and MarkID

Here is my code:

```
Drop procedure if exists coursework.UpdateStudentMark;

DELIMITER //
Create procedure coursework.UpdateStudentMark
(
IN Message varchar(500) ,
IN StudentID text,
IN Academic_Year int,
IN Module_Code_And_Title text,
IN Module_Mark int
)

BEGIN 

insert into logging_table (AuditText, timestamp )
        values ( Message,  now() );

update coursework.mark as mark
 INNER JOIN
   coursework.Modules USING (ModuleID)
          INNER JOIN
    coursework.department USING (DeptID)
    INNER JOIN
    coursework.course USING (DeptID) 
    INNER JOIN
   coursework.student USING (CourseID , SID)
    
set 
Module_Mark = mark.Module_Mark
Where student.StudentID = StudentID  AND student.Academic_Year= Academic_Year AND  Modules.Module_Code_And_Title = Module_Code_And_Title;


END;
//
Delimiter ;
```

I called the stored procedure by this code:

```
Call coursework.UpdateStudentMark ('Update Student Stats' ,'B3984673', 2018, 'EEEE3001: Third Year Project [FY]' , 1);
```

Comment: If you copy/paste the `update` query and run it in another tool, does it update as expected?

Comment: I do not have another tool to run it but I might try that

Comment: You should not give parameters the same name as columns or declared variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it after I gave a new name which different from the declared variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um... correct me if I'm wrong, but you're just updating a column to be itself (setting `mark.Module_Mark` = `mark.Module_Mark`) e.g.,

```
update coursework.mark as mark
      <...>
set 
Module_Mark = mark.Module_Mark
```

Comment: I thought if I use Module_Mark, it will be referred to the Module_Mark of the procedure "UpdateStudentMark". Is that right?

Comment: For an UPDATE statement, the SET is <the column you wish you update> = <the value you wish to update it to>. Maybe you mean (effectively) `set mark.Module_Mark = Module_Mark` - however, I'm not sure how mysql will deal with the ambiguous names (e.g., both the column name and the parameter being called Module_Mark).

Comment: Yes, the ambiguous names were the main issue. Thank you so much!!